# What did you there? What do you then? Why are they grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

In literature I meet such questions: What did you there? What do you then? Why are they grammatically correct?

> Pussycat pussycat, where have you been? I've been up to London to
>   visit the Queen. Pussycat pussycat, **what did you there**? I frightened a
>   little mouse under her chair

In another source of this poem I saw '**what you did there**?'

> "We will need men," Zouga said. "What will you do when you have them?"
>   Jan Cheroot asked. "Dig the stuff out." "And then?" the little
>   Hottentot demanded with a malicious gleam in his dark eyes, his
>   features wrinkled as a sour windfallen apple. "**What do you then**?"
>   he insisted.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?  I think you may be talking about obsolete dialects.

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77760/what-did-you-there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were grammatical several hundred years ago, but are not used in contemporary English.

Today we would ask:

What *did* you **do** there?

using *did* as an auxiliary to form the past tense in combination with bare infinitive **do**.

*What saw you there?* would become today *What did you see there?*

Comment: Is it possible the character is not meant to be a native speaker and is using some kind of *pidgin* dialect?